# qTranslate + Woocommerce разные цены для разных стран

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возможно ли менять цену товара в зависимости от выбранного языка через qTranslate в woocommerce? Если да, то через какой плагин или интеграцию?

Comment: Если есть возможность скрывать страницы, тоже подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Все было достаточно просто. Так как товары являются постами, то можно подменять данные в БД.

Пример:
[image: Вставляем в БД коды подмены языка в таблицу с ценой и id постом]

Таким образом можно добиться изменения цен на сайте в зависимости от языка. Данное решение является костылем.